# Checking Remaining Disk Space Linux

Tags: linux, partition, usb, disk-usage, disk

How to display all connected usb devices on a centos 7 machine showing remaining disk space?

I have tried `lsblk` but that does not show free disk space ...

```
lsblk
```

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). Just copypaste into a code block instead.

Comment: you mean like the disk free program, `df`?

Answer (score 0):

```
df -h
```

will show available and used space on partitions

```
sudo du -hsx /* | sort -rh
```

full details of each folder (change `/*` for custom path)

```
ls -lah
```

will show about each file

you can use `grep` command to target it

```
df -h | grep /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 0):

`lsblk` lists block devices. The command you're looking for is `df`, which reports disk usage.

Assuming all your USB devices are mounted on `/media/usb<n>`, the command you're looking for is

```
df -h /media/usb*
```

(thanks @tripleee. The command `df -h | grep "/media/usb"` would also work for that purpose.)

Comment: ... or better `df -h /media/usb*`